# AndroidRuntime java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

I am newbie and trying to call an object of a class that exists in library. Basically my goal is to authenticate user from the PHP Application. 
com.test.app.library  and the code of the file is as following:

```
package com.test.app.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.util.Log;

/* Helper class for sending requests to our system
* AND MANAGEMENT RESPONSE. */
public class Httppostaux {

InputStream is = null;
String result = "";

public JSONArray getserverdataMapp(ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters,
        String urlwebserver) {

    httppostconnect(parameters, urlwebserver);

    if (is != null) {// si obtuvo una respuesta

        getpostresponse();

        return getjsonarray();

    } else {

        return null;

    }

}

// peticion HTTP
private void httppostconnect(ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametros, String urlwebserver) {
    Log.e("Test","Inside  post.");
    //
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlwebserver);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametros));
        // ejecuto peticion enviando datos por POST
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

}

public void getpostresponse() {

    // Convierte respuesta a String
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("getpostresponse", " result= " + sb.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
}

public JSONArray getjsonarray() {
    // parse json data
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        return jArray;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

When I try to call in the following code:

```
package com.test.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.test.app.library.Httppostaux;
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * Activity which displays a login screen to the user, offering registration as
 * well.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
// private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;
  Httppostaux post;
  String URL_connect = "http://devstagemp.zerocall.com/b2c.php/pScripts/appLogin";

/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */

// Values for user name and password at the time of the login attempt.
private String mUserName;
private String mPassword;
private String mPincode;

// UI references.
private EditText mUserNameView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private EditText mPincodeView;
private View mLoginFormView;
private View mLoginStatusView;
private TextView mLoginStatusMessageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Set up the login form.

    mUserNameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPincodeView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pincode);
    mPasswordView
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id,
                        KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                        attemptLogin();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mLoginStatusView = findViewById(R.id.login_status);
    mLoginStatusMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status_message);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });
}

// @Override
// public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
// getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);
// return true;
// }

/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid user name, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
public void attemptLogin() {
    // if (mAuthTask != null) {
    // return;
    // }
    // Reset errors.
    mUserNameView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);
    mPincodeView.setError(null);
    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    mUserName = mUserNameView.getText().toString();
    mPassword = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
    mPincode = mPincodeView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPassword)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (mPassword.length() < 6) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid user name.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUserName)) {
        mUserNameView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mUserNameView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (mUserName.length() < 4) {
        mUserNameView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_username));
        focusView = mUserNameView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for the Input

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPincode)) {
        mPincodeView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mPincodeView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        mLoginStatusMessageView.setText(R.string.login_progress_signing_in);
        // Authentication;
        new asynclogin().execute(mUserName, mPassword,mPincode);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                                : View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */

public void err_login() {
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(200);
    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Error:Nombre de usuario o password incorrectos",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast1.show();
}

public boolean loginstatus(String username, String password,String pincode) {
    int logstatus = -1;

    /*
     * Creamos un ArrayList del tipo nombre valor para agregar los datos
     * recibidos por los parametros anteriores y enviarlo mediante POST a
     * nuestro sistema para relizar la validacion
     */
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postparameters2send = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pincode", pincode));

    // realizamos una peticion y como respuesta obtenes un array JSON
    Log.e("URL",postparameters2send.toString());
    JSONArray jdata = post.getserverdataMapp(postparameters2send, URL_connect);

    /*
     * como estamos trabajando de manera local el ida y vuelta sera casi
     * inmediato para darle un poco realismo decimos que el proceso se pare
     * por unos segundos para poder observar el progressdialog la podemos
     * eliminar si queremos
     */
    SystemClock.sleep(950);

    // si lo que obtuvimos no es null
    if (jdata != null && jdata.length() > 0) {

        JSONObject json_data; // creamos un objeto JSON
        try {
            json_data = jdata.getJSONObject(0); // leemos el primer segmento
                                                // en nuestro caso el unico
            logstatus = json_data.getInt("logstatus");// accedemos al valor
            Log.e("loginstatus", "logstatus= " + logstatus);// muestro por
                                                            // log que
                                                            // obtuvimos
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // validamos el valor obtenido
        if (logstatus == 0) {// [{"logstatus":"0"}]
            Log.e("loginstatus ", "invalido");
            return false;
        } else {// [{"logstatus":"1"}]
            Log.e("loginstatus ", "valido");
            return true;
        }

    } else { // json obtenido invalido verificar parte WEB.
        Log.e("JSON  ", "ERROR");
        return false;
    }

}

class asynclogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String user, pass,pin;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // para el progress dialog

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // obtnemos usr y pass
        user = params[0];
        pass = params[1];
        pin = params[2];

        // enviamos y recibimos y analizamos los datos en segundo plano.
        if (loginstatus(user, pass,pin) == true) {
            return "ok"; // login valido
        } else {
            return "err"; // login invalido
        }

    }

    /*
     * Una vez terminado doInBackground segun lo que halla ocurrido pasamos
     * a la sig. activity o mostramos error
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.e("onPostExecute=", "" + result);

        if (result.equals("ok")) {

            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashBoard.class);
            i.putExtra("user", user);
            startActivity(i);

        } else {
            err_login();
        }

    }

}

}
```

I am receiving the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1591): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at com.test.app.LoginActivity.loginstatus(LoginActivity.java:237)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at com.test.app.LoginActivity$asynclogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:295)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at com.test.app.LoginActivity$asynclogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                        E/AndroidRuntime(1591):     ... 5 more
```

Internet Permissions are there in the android manifest file.

Comment: You should read about CamelCase for improving your naming.

Comment: What is line 237 in LoginActivity? The error occurs there...

Comment: On line 237: JSONArray jdata = post.getserverdataMeasypay(postparameters2send, URL_connect); the post is the object of the Httppostaux class that is in library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post` is null. Remember to instantiate it before accessing it.

Comment: @Baran don't expect the code to work, make it work. Be paranoid about your parameters and what you're using if you get an NPE it means you didn't configure something properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have an NPE at LoginActivity.java:237 Ensure that none of the parameters are null and ensure they are property configured **BEFORE** you pass them in.

Comment: I have checked the parameters using Log.e they have values.
How should i Configure it. what is NPE :( Sorry I am really new to Android and Java as well.

Comment: ensure during processing that the task is not running with a null value, NPE (Null Pointer Exception)

Comment: URL_connect and postparameters2send both have values. What I guess its not able to call the getserverdataMeasypay function of the post object.

Comment: As @eightx2 mentioned you do have a null value. Check that.